# access asp calendar from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have a mix of js and asp charts on a web page. I would like the js charts to update when on the post back of the calendar. is there a way to get the selected date from the calendar using js?

Comment: I have used <%= MyCalendar.SelectedDate %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="auto-style1"><strong>From Date: </strong></span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#<%= txtFrom.ClientID  %>").datepicker();
    $("#<%= txtTo.ClientID  %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using an asp:calendar :(

Comment: @MatthewKnudsen Please include information like that in your post.  Its impossible to give a correct answer with out ALL the information.